# How to add custom pseudoclass, affecting entire row in TableView?

Tags: java, css, tableview, javafx-8, pseudo-class

I have added custom pseudoclass to my own class of cell, which was then decorated with yellow background in CSS. Unfortunately, this affected only cells:

[image]

Is it possible to mark entire row with pseudoclass?

**PLEASE, NOTE THE TAGS**

Question is NOT related with `Javascript` and `HTML`. It is related with desktop programming library of `JavaFX`, which is also using `CSS`.

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make entire row styled once I create not custom [`TableCell`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/TableCell.html), but custom [`TableRow`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/TableRow.html). It is [explicitly said in Javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/TableRow.html#TableRow--), that namely this class has CSS class of `table-row-cell`, which was initially confusing me. It means "cell, representing an entire row of a table".

So, by supplying pseudoclasses to this class, I was able to color entire row correctly.